# Replace newline characters with <br>\n using regex in Emacs Lisp function

Tags: regex, emacs, replace, elisp

I want to replace all newline characters with `<br>\n` in markdown mode. I wrote this code. It doesn't work.

```
(add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (local-set-key (kbd "<f2>")
                           (lambda ()
                             (interactive)
                             (save-excursion
                               (beginning-of-buffer)
                               (while (re-search-forward "\(<br>\)?\n" nil t)
                                 (replace-match "<br>\n" nil nil))
                               (save-buffer))))))
```

But if I call `replace-regexp` interactively in a buffer with regex `\(<br>\)?C-q C-j` and replace string `<br>C-q C-j`, it works. I've been struggled on this for a while. What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string is not escaped.  Try `"\\(<br>\\)?\n"`.